# Cannot invoke "save" with an argument list of type "(nil)'

Tags: ios, core-data

need help with the blow code.  Just updated to Xcode 7 beta

I get the following error "Cannot invoke "save" with an argument list of type "(nil)'".  This was working in IOS 6

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ItemViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldDiveNumber: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldDiveDate: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldDiveLocation: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
@IBAction func saveTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let contxt: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    let en = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("List", inManagedObjectContext: contxt)

    var newItem = Model(entity: (en)!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: contxt)

    newItem.divenumber = textFieldDiveNumber.text!
    newItem.divedate = textFieldDiveDate.text!
    newItem.divelocation = textFieldDiveLocation.text!

    contxt.save(nil)



    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



}
```

Comment: have you tried passing in `NULL`?

Comment: Yes I have, it states the NULL is unavailable, use 'nil' instead of this imported macro

Answer (score 2):

This has been asked several times since last Monday, but finding & marking duplicates from the SE iOS app is cumbersome, so...

In Swift 2, `NSManagedObjectContext`'s `save()` method is marked `throws`, so you have to handle any error that comes from it. (And you don't pass an error pointer as a parameter.)

Your Swift 1 code is ignoring errors; the Swift 2 equivalent is an empty `catch`:

```
do {
    try context.save()
} catch {
    // you can go about your business. move along. 
}
```

Ignoring errors isn't a great idea, though. If you don't want to make an error user-recoverable by doing something useful in that `catch`, just plan to crash on error:

```
try! context.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanx Rickster, I did come across and tried your method earlier in the day but it didn't work.
But when you re-posted your answer I tried it again only this time using "contxt" instead of "context" and it worked.
Thank you very much.
Regards.
Del