# contxt.save(nil) - Extra Argument In Call

Tags: ios, xcode7

This question has arisen numerous times, but I still haven't found a satisfactory resolution for Xcode 7 Beta.

An error appears on the following line:-

contxt.save(nil) {

The error states...... "Extra argument in call"

what does this mean and can someone please show me the Swift coding required to solve this error?

I have copied most of my code below.

Thanx  Del

```
@IBOutlet weak var locationTextField: UITextField! = nil
@IBOutlet weak var areaTextField: UITextField! = nil
@IBOutlet weak var postCodeTextField: UITextField! = nil
@IBOutlet weak var longLatTextField: UITextField! = nil
@IBOutlet weak var remarksTextField: UITextField! = nil


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func saveButtonPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    //Reference To Our App Delegate
    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    // Reference moc
    let contxt: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    let en = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("list", inManagedObjectContext: contxt)

    // Create Instance Of Our Data Model And Initialise

    let newItem = Model(entity: en!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: contxt)

    // Map Our Properties
    newItem.location = locationTextField.text!
    newItem.area = areaTextField.text!
    newItem.postCode = postCodeTextField.text!
    newItem.longLat = longLatTextField.text!
    newItem.remarks = remarksTextField.text!

    // Save Our Context
```

//        contxt.save(&ErrorType.self)
//            print(newItem)

```
    contxt.save(nil) {

    print(newItem)

    // Navigate Back To Root vc

    self.navigationController!.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

}


 func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: What if you pass NULL?

Comment: Take a look at [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30834493/3985749) - I think this is a result of new error handling in Swift 2.

Comment: null produces the following error:- ....Use of unresolved identifier 'null'

Comment: ( ) produces the error ..... Cannot invoke 'save' with an argument list of type '(() -> _)'

Comment: click on pbasdf answer above for solution. Thanks all for your replies.